# Dynamically change the behavior of member functions in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pointer-to-member

For a homework, we need to modify a variety of images with multiple different algorithms and format a document with our answers. I have already coded the algorithms in C++, but I want to write a program that will modify the images and format the document automatically. To do this, I want to have a class of the form

```
class A
{
    void f1(Image img)
    {
    // do something to the image
    }
    void f2(Image img)
    {
    // do something else to the image
    }
    public:
       void setFunction(bool choice)
       {
          if(choice)
          {
          // define this.operator() = f1
          }
          else
          {
          // define this.operator() = f2
          }
       }
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because the homework requires us to compute different properties for the images, but most of the properties are repeated accross questions. Therefore, I want to write a single function of the form

```
void answerQuestion(Image img, A imgProcessor)
{
    // load img, call imgProcessor(img)
    // and get the necessary properties from
    // img to answer the questions
}
```

This way, I can just do something like `imgProcessor.setFunction(choice)` before passing the `imgProcessor` object to `answerQuestion`. I want to use an object because questions are split into several parts, so I would like the `imgProcessor` object to hold on to some information required for the rest of the problem. 
I don't know how to dynamically define or redefine the `operator()` method, or if it is even possible. Of course, I am indifferent between overloading the call operator or just declaring my own method, but I want to be able to use this call in the same way accross the code. Is this possible in C++?

Comment: Make an array or vector of member function pointers or `std::function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to somehow remember the choice.  In C++, function pointers and function objects don't participate in overload resolution so you cannot *actually* replace `operator()()` with a different function, but you certainly can write `operator()()` with some type of conditional that checks the choice selected earlier and decides which function to call.

Comment: So the best way of doing this is writing an array of member function pointers as suggested by NathanOliver and then storing an index to call the correct function in the definition of ```operator()()```?

Comment: @GuachoPerez: Or store the specific member function pointer itself instead of the index.  The important piece is to make the dynamic call inside the body of `operator()()`, that way there is always a `operator()()` function that the compiler can see and use for operation overload resolution.  Sometimes a function whose sole purpose is to call another function immediately is called a "trampoline" or "shim".